# what is the 'a' that is added to CSS classes

Tags: css

so I have this CSS file and it has this

```
.post > a {
    position: absolute;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 22px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

and I'm not sure what does the a means exactly?

Comment: It's just the `<a>` tag. i.e. a link. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

Comment: Just look in prefix: `.` - class, `#` - id, no-prefix - simple tag name

Comment: Here's some info on css selectors for future reference: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Answer (score 0):

Selects all `<a>` elements where the parent is an element with a class `post`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator

Comment: I upvoted this, but just one minor thing: the link to the documentation for the `<a>` tag is not really relevant on its own (since the question is really about what the "> a" means), so if I may suggest an edit - I think the answer would be improved if you added this link as well: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator